# How do you exclude folders when searching?

Tags: sublimetext

I looked here:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsublimetext%5D+search+exclude+folder

but did not find an answer.  I don't want to modify the configuration as I want to keep the folder in the side bar.

`-*.txt` appears to not search text files but I want to exclude my build directory as such:

`/build`

I tried

`-/build`

but this did not work.

This is after using Control-Shift-F to bring up the search bar.

Comment: Did you try `-build/*`? `/build` means the directory `/build` in the root of your file system, not the root of your project.

Comment: similar to .gitignore file ... I will try

Answer (score 0):

Filters like -dist.* don't work, only option add 'dist' to sublime user settings folder_exclude_patterns, after search exclude it

```
"folder_exclude_patterns": [".svn", ".git", ".hg", "CVS", "dist"]
```